# sp_send_dbmail will not send query results

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, sp-send-dbmail

I've tried every avenue on every damn forum suggested, but to no avail!
Need to send results of SQLPERF(logspace), that have been stored in a table, via `sp_send_dbmail` to recipient.

Step 2 of job is where failure occurs. Please help!

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name= 'MyDBA',
@recipients= 'Mack@mydba.co.za',
@subject='Log Warning',
@query='SELECT * from #TempForLogSpace WHERE LogSpaceUsed >80
```

Comment: Did you notice the missing closing quote from `@query`?

Answer (score 10):

You can't query from a temp table using database mail.  The session that you used to create the temp table (step 1 of your job I assume) has been closed and a new session started when step 2 started.  Because the session has been closed the table has been dropped (even if the table hasn't been dropped because it's a new session you don't have access to the other sessions temp table).

Either create a physical table and use that (either in the tempdb database or your database) or put the code which creates the output in the @query with the select * from #TempForLogSpace at the end (a stored procedure will be much easier to deal with in this case).

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is a bit old, but in case someone stumbles on this, the problem is like mrdenny said that sp_send_dbmail stored procedure runs in it's own session, however you can get around this by using a global temporary table instead (prefix the table with two pound signs (##)).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a global temp table like `##temp_table`. This table will be accessible by all sessions and will remain in database until all sessions that referred it have been closed.

[Local and global temporary tables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920836/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server)