# Monitoring long running batch in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm looking to monitor a long running script in Sql Server 2008.

I'm searching for an equivalent of [`dbms_application_info`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm#i999254) in oracle. I want to set a status on the session during runtime and monitor using some kind of `v$session` table.

I know I can set up an event table but I thought that maybe there is a build in solution (though i highly doubt it having dealt with sql server for a while now).

Comment: How about [`SET CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) / [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx)?

Comment: Or use a *temporary* status table -- either via a table variable `@table` (local to the batch), or as a temporary local table `#table` (local to the session).

Comment: @stakk - i see that's it allow only binary data. I'm looking to set string, e.g "Stated loading data into fact...";

Comment: About the temporary table - wouldn't such table be accessible only to the process/session running the batch ? I'm looking to monitor the process from another session.

Comment: In that case, you would want a global temporary table `##table`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2921091/240733) to the question, ["Local and global temporary tables in SQL Server"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920836/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server) for an explanation of the difference.