# Select into table command not working in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

So I've been executing this in a C# form:

```
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = common.DBConnect();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        Int32 rowsAffected;

        cmd.CommandText = "Select * into #temp1 from web.web_entry";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

The problem is this command was executed no errors or whatsoever, but when I tried to select from this temporary table in SQL server, this table isn't existing.

Comment: Temporary tables are visible only to the connection that creates it, and are deleted when the connection is closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920836/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server

Comment: so what I'll do is I will not close the connection until I have made a select query out of it?

Comment: You should use stored procedure. Inside stored procedure you can create temp table and use that temp table for select. That is how it is done in general practice.

Comment: Why you need that Temp table outside the application? As @Priyank suggested you have to use Stored Procedure for selecting temp table data after the insert statement.

Comment: Actually there are conditions set to the real query that I'm executing, and I want to create a temporary table for that so in my second query I can do a filtering of records and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have figured it out. What I did was I executed both queries before I close the connection and then return a datatable out of it so I can see the records retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

Temp tables will be removed after the session witch create them ends
so when you close the connection sqlserver drops them

Comment: yah, I didn't notice that while I was executing my query, so everytime that it runs, it was gone before I execute my query for selecting records out of it.