# Temporary tables in a WHILE LOOP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a question concerning a dynamic creation of temporary tables.

I need a *while loop* in which temporary tables are created in every cycle differing in their name using the variable `@i`. So I specified the variables `@CreateTableVerbGES` and `@ShowTableVerbGES` with the code as strings and want to execute them in the loop.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @CreateTableVerbGES nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ShowTableVerbGES nvarchar (max)

WHILE @i<4

BEGIN

SET @CreateTableVerbGES = 'CREATE TABLE #UnterBaugruppe'+CAST((@i) as nvarchar(max))+' ([IDTBG] [int] identity(1,1),[IDGES] [int] NULL,[Baugruppe1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,[IDBG1] [int] NULL,[Bauteil1] [int] NULL,[Baugruppe2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,[IDBG2] [int] NULL,[Bauteil2] [int] NULL,[Baugruppe3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,[IDBG3] [int] NULL,[Bauteil3] [int] NULL)'

SET @ShowTableVerbGES = 'SELECT * FROM #UnterBaugruppe'+CAST((@i) as nvarchar(max))

EXEC (@CreateTableVerbGES)
EXEC (@ShowTableVerbGES)

SET @i += 1

END
```

The problem is that it seems like the first cycle of the loop is running, because the first table `#UnterBaugruppe1` is shown. But for the next two cycles there is a warning that the tables `#UnterBaugruppe2` and `#UnterBaugruppe3` are invalid and don't exist.

Does anybody have an idea why it isn't working?

I really need the tables in a loop because I want to insert different information in the loop as well dependent on `@i`.

Comment: I don't understand anything, give table structure, give table sample data, and tell us what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: Give it a shot to go with 'CREATE TABLE ##UnterBaugruppe' and let me know if its working ... ofc don't forget to 'SELECT * FROM ##UnterBaugruppe'

Comment: The table structure and everything conerning the table is defined in 'CreateTableVerbGES'. This varaible is a string containing the complete code for creating a table. Since I want to create the tables in a loop with the 'i' as a variable table name, I safed the code in a variable so that I just have to execute it in the loop.

Comment: I think that `SET @i += 1` is not valid in tsql. what server version do you have?

Comment: Ok, I tried it with ##UnterBaugruppe! That works. Thanks! But if I want to run the loop a second time it always tells me that the table already exists. Is there a way to first proof if the table exists and if it does to delete it?

Comment: It should be `SET @i = @i + 1`

Comment: Hi Luis, the @i += 1 is working. I already tried that in another loop!

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.dbo.##UnterBaugruppe'+CAST((@i) as nvarchar(max))) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##UnterBaugruppe'+CAST((@i) as nvarchar(max))

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920836/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server

Comment: Great! The DROP command is working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: A table namend with two hashtags ## is a global temporary table. So it can be used from every session. And if multiple sessions run the same TSQL-Statement it might not be doing what it should be.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just concatenated the dynamic sql of two variable into single using new line character and executed and it perfectly worked for me!

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @CreateTableVerbGES nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ShowTableVerbGES nvarchar (max)

WHILE @i<4

BEGIN

SET @CreateTableVerbGES = 'CREATE TABLE #UnterBaugruppe'+CAST((@i) as nvarchar(max))+' ([IDTBG] [int] identity(1,1),[IDGES] [int] NULL,[Baugruppe1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,[IDBG1] [int] NULL,[Bauteil1] [int] NULL,[Baugruppe2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,[IDBG2] [int] NULL,[Bauteil2] [int] NULL,[Baugruppe3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,[IDBG3] [int] NULL,[Bauteil3] [int] NULL)'
+ CHar(10) + Char(13) + 'SELECT * FROM #UnterBaugruppe'+CAST((@i) as nvarchar(max)) + CHar(10) + Char(13) 

Print @CreateTableVerbGES
EXEC (@CreateTableVerbGES)
--EXEC (@ShowTableVerbGES)

SET @i += 1

END
```

Comment: Good idea! I will try that as well!