# why is #[table name] used in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking at some production SQL scripts and I see some table names that start with a hash #. Like,

```
select * from #tmp
```

or

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP table #tmp;
```

Does # have an actual meaning? Why use it?

Comment: The `#` indicates a temporary table in SQL Server.

Comment: To add to what @GordonLinoff said, `#` denotes a `LOCAL` temporary table (visible in a single session, where it was created). `##` will denote a `GLOBAL` temporary table, visible in all sessions (to all users connected to SQL Server). It will basically be pretty much like a persisted table, available to all users, until the server gets restarted. After that, it's gone.

Comment: You may find this helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920836/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server/2921091