# SQL - Running a Job once a day that every 25 minutes makes an insert statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a question regarding stored procedures and SQL. I have a job running everyday containing a stored procedure which makes an insert into a database table.

This is the current situation: I have to insert the data about yesterday, in this stored procedure I take the data of today, decrease 1 day and save the elements in my DB, in this way I have the data of yesterday.

This is the **desired situation**: I have to insert the data about the previous week, starting from yesterday.

In the stored procedure, I want to do the following steps:

- I set the data of yesterday and I make the first insert
- After 25 minutes I decrease one day so that I have the data of 2 days before and I insert the data
- I repeat the same process until the number of days I've defined is lower than a counter I increase every time I make an insert

Question: how in SQL can I write: wait for 25 minutes then do this?

I couldn't simply run the job every 25 minutes because, when I decrease the date (the date is the name of the table such as data_20210926), I should know the starting date (is it today - 3, today - 4 or else) and I can't know this information and the job in my system can't have in input the result of the output of the previous execution

Comment: You could create a [TempDb permanent table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921091/205233) to store information to pass between runs instead of waiting which may prove more robust.

Comment: [Waitfor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Procedural code (like stored procedures) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.