# Create Temp Table Using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I wanted to create many temp tables in a loop and insert data, but when I ran a test with this simple dynamic SQL, it ran successfully, but there was no tabled created. Could someone please help me? Thank you in advance.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#blankOuputLevel2') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #blankOuputLevel2
END

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE #blankOuputLevel2 (tjob NVARCHAR(30));'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

This code runs successfully.

Then I run the `SELECT` shown below, and get an error:

> Invalid object name '#blankOuputLevel2'

```
SELECT * FROM #blankOuputLevel2
```

Comment: You need to create *and use* the table all in dynamic SQL.

Comment: in The dynamic SQL , temp table created in a The dynamic SQL is dropped automatically(only exist in the scope of the query ).you can use Real table or global temp table(##TableName) which will can see outside the scope of the dynamic query(This seession and other session).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is how (local) temporary tables `#Temp` work.

They are automatically dropped when they get out of scope.

Your temp table is created within the context / scope of the stored procedure `sp_executesql` and it is dropped automatically when this stored procedure returns.

You can try to use global temporary tables `##Temp`, but as Aaron Bertrand pointed out: "Global temp tables are only useful when you can guarantee single concurrency; if two users run the same code and reference `##whatever`, they’re going to trample all over each other. And when you can guarantee single concurrency, I’d just use a permanent table."

In many cases you can put all your code in the dynamic SQL string to execute as a single batch by a single call to `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE #blankOuputLevel2 (tjob NVARCHAR(30)); '
SET @sql = @sql + 'INSERT INTO #blankOuputLevel2 .....;'
SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT ... FROM #blankOuputLevel2 .....;'
SET @sql = @sql + '... the rest of your logic using #blankOuputLevel2 ...'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

In this case the local temp table `#blankOuputLevel2` will be visible to the code that you put in the `@sql` and it will be dropped after `sp_executesql` finishes.
You can run several instances of this dynamic code simultaneously and each instance will get its own separate temp table.

---

For more details about various temporary tables in SQL Server have a look at this question [Local and global temporary tables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2920836/4116017):

- **Table variables** (`DECLARE @t TABLE`) are visible only to the connection that creates it, and are deleted when the batch or stored procedure ends.
- **Local temporary tables** (`CREATE TABLE #t`) are visible only to the
  connection that creates it, and are deleted when the connection is
  closed.
- **Global temporary tables** (`CREATE TABLE ##t`) are visible to everyone,
  and are deleted when all connections that have referenced them have closed.
- **Tempdb permanent tables** (`USE tempdb CREATE TABLE t`) are visible to
  everyone, and are deleted when the server is restarted.

[Temporary tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#temporary-tables)

> Temporary tables are automatically dropped when they go out of scope,
> unless explicitly dropped by using DROP TABLE:
>
> - A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped    automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be
>   referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored
>   procedure that created the table. The table can't be referenced by
>   the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.
> - All other local temporary tables are dropped automatically at the end    of the current session.
> - Global temporary tables are automatically    dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other    tasks have
>   stopped referencing them. The association between a task    and a
>   table is maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL
>   statement. This means that a global temporary table is dropped at the
>   completion of the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively
>   referencing the table when the creating session ended.

Comment: Global temp tables are only useful when you can guarantee single concurrency; if two users run the same code and reference ##whatever, they’re going to trample all over each other. And when you can guarantee single concurrency, I’d just use a permanent table.

Comment: Valid point, @AaronBertrand

Comment: Thank you @VladimirBaranov and AaronBertrand for the super helpful information!